# JavaFX FXMLLoader: location is not set when loading from jar-file

Tags: java, javafx, jar, fxml, illegalstateexception

I have this problem that when I export my project to a jar-file, then I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```

It's caused when I try to make my view which looks like this:

```
public View(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("MapsRUs");
    Scene scene = loader.load();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I have a resources folder in which the view.fxml file is located.

I figured it can't find the view.fxml-file but it works fine when I run it from IntelliJ. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check to make sure your FXML file was included in the JAR file and that you're using the correct, _case-sensitive_ path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was because it was with small "v" instead of large "V" - it works now that I adjusted to the case sensitive file name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help from Slaw:
It was because it was with small "v" instead of large "V" - it works now that I adjusted to the case sensitive file name